# Xls to Json, header xls on multiple lines

Tags: java, json, parsing, apache-poi, xls

I need to convert a xls file to json. Below is the strucure of the file I need to parse:

[image]

The parsing works, used the code:

```
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
          ----
            }
        }
    }
    workbook.close();
```

How can I get for example project[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8mDv.jpg) = applicability, project[2] = commitment etc (so for Project I have 3 subcolumns, I need to get all the subcolumns). Also I can have 2 or 3 lines header, there is a generic solution for such headers, because my file can have different fields?

Currentely I receive the header fields in order, id, title, revision, project, applicability, commitment, justification, because I read cell by cell.

I want to map project.applicability to a cell result, currentely is complicated to determine which cell is what. My header contains more header cells, this is a snapshot.

Comment: Switch to fetching by row/column as per http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator ?

Comment: What is `project[1]` and `project[2]`?  Do you mean the headers could be in a different order?  Seems like there should be a `List` where each row is used to populate a POJO and add to the `List`.  Later, transform the `List` to  JSON.

Comment: I mean progect is the super header and his childs are [applicability, commitment, justification] so project[1] = applicability. I hope is clear.

Comment: It doesn't work on a  generic case, need to know which are the child cells of a super cell.